# bat file to open up a chrome browser window with no toolbars

Tags: batch-file

How to use a bat file to open up a chrome browser window with no toolbars.(just like a popup window)

```
@echo off
start "Chrome" chrome --new-window http://localhost/jayambe/
```

this code when run opens up a chrome browser with the required url but i don't need the toolbars on the top also the window should open maximized.

it must look something like this

[image]

please help

Comment: Javascript can bring up a window.. Something like this but you want it done in a batch file http://www.textfixer.com/html/javascript-pop-up-window.php  So perhaps you could add javascript as a tag

Comment: If you want to ask about making an EXE then don't ask it in this question

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it is called Application Mode, and will remove any toolbars:

`start "Chrome" chrome --app=http://example.com/`

Note this will also remove the address bar.

Comment: sir, this code doesn't even opens the url. it just shows up a blank window with toolbars.

Comment: @SreedevVJ check again, it looked right to me, so I just copied and pasted that exact line into `cmd` prompt and chrome opened correctly in app mode (without toolbars) and loaded the example.com example page.

Comment: yes it works but my ultimate aim is to make a bat file and convert it into a standalone exe for deployment. how can i make this idea work with the code?

Comment: got the solution, i saved it as a filename.cmd file and used Bat To Exe Converter software to convert it to exe but another issue is to make the window open in full screen mode when the exe of cmd file is launched. please help with that.

Comment: @SreedevVJ those are two different questions. Don't mix making an EXE question, with a what command line to start chrome question

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`start "Chrome" chrome --new-window javascript:window.open("example.com");`